# Script to create directory and subdirectory in sftp

Tags: bash, shell, sftp

I am running a Bash script to upload the file to an sftp location. However, before uploading the file, I need to check if the sftp directory and sub-directories exist or not. If they exist then upload a file, if not then create the directory and sub-directories and then upload the file. How can I achieve this?

`mkdir -p` is not working in sftp. Unfortunately the ssh access is disabled. I have tried this:

```
for i in `ls -1t | head -1`
do
        echo $i
        zip -r $i_file.zip $i
        sleep 2
        sshpass -p "passowrd" sftp -oPort=22 username@sftpserver <<< $'cd /file \n mkdir file1/file2/file3 \n cd /file1/file2/file3 \n put '$I_file.zip''
done
```

Comment: you might want to use a better client. Investigate `lftp`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if the directory exists if not try this, I don't how it will play out using sftp client because I am kind of novice too but thought to give it a try. I would love to hear your feedback or anyone else's for that matter.

```
#!/bin/bash
path="$1"
if [ ! -d "$path" ]
then
    IFS='/' # space is set as delimiter
    read -ra ADDR <<< "$path" # str is read into an array as tokens separated by IFS'
    cdir="$PWD"
    for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do # access each element of array
        cdir+="/$i"
        mkdir "$cdir"
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried this:
>
> ```
> for i in `ls -1t | head -1`
> do
>         echo $i
>         zip -r $i_file.zip $i
>         sleep 2
>         sshpass -p "passowrd" sftp -oPort=22 username@sftpserver <<< $'cd /file \n mkdir file1/file2/file3 \n cd /file1/file2/file3 \n put '$I_file.zip''
> done
> ```

- `$i_file.zip` - If identifier characters are to be appended to the variable expansion, the name must be embraced: `${i}_file.zip`.
- `cd /file \n mkdir file1/file2/file3 \n cd /file1/file2/file3 \n` - You change to */file*, (try to) create */file/file1/file2/file3* and then try to change to */file1/file2/file3*. Perhaps you meant `cd /file1 \n mkdir file2 \n mkdir file2/file3 \n cd file2/file3 \n`.
- `$I_file.zip` - You have a capital `I` instead of the lower case `i` in braces: `${i}_file.zip`.